# How to define NOT is sanity.io structure builder?

Tags: javascript, sanity, groq

I'm trying to filter all products without categories (which is array of references) and can't find how to do it.

```
S.listItem()
  .title('Without category')
  .id('productsWithoutCategories')
    .child(
      S.documentList()
        .title('Without categories')
        .menuItems(S.documentTypeList('product').getMenuItems())
        .filter('_type == $type && !category')
        .params({ type: 'product' })
      )
```

`!category` not working.
 I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finded answer with Vision (really pleasant tool)

https://www.sanity.io/docs/the-vision-plugin

```
 .filter('_type == $type && !defined(categories)')
 .params({ type: 'product' })
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've already found out yourself, you can use the `defined` function to check if something is set (or not set by using the NOT operator `!`). You can find some documentation regarding the `defined` function here:

- https://www.sanity.io/docs/how-queries-work#more-ways-to-filter-99fd60e475f2
- https://www.sanity.io/docs/query-cheat-sheet#functions-a1da4a3b2adc

Just want to quote from the documentation as well:

> You'll never see a null value on a document stored in Sanity. If you update a value to null, that key will disappear. Thus, the is null constraint you may know from SQL does not bear any meaning here. A value is either `defined` or `!defined`.

And from the How Queries Work page:

> Filtering by the presence of a field, e.g. `*[defined(status)]` which only match document that have the status property set to any value.